# Thunderbird: Get Subject dynamically in HTML Signature

Tags: html, signature, data-transfer, thunderbird

i need to add a wetransfer link in thunderbird html signature to allow clients upload files directly in my account.

I want to give them the wetransfer link with pre-filled title based on subject of email `https://wetransfersupport.wetransfer.com/?title=EMAIL%20SUBJECT`

Is there anything like `{{SUBJECT}}` to add in title parameter?